# Power BI - Filtered count not grouping by values in table

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have two tables (subject & category) that are both related to the same parent table (main).  Because of the foreign key constraints, it looks like Power BI automatically created the links.

[Simple mock-up of table links](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUqw6.png)

I need to count the subjects by type for each possible distance range.  I tried a simple calculation shown below for each distance category.

```
less than 2m = 
CALCULATE(
    COUNTA('Category'[Descr]),
    'Subject'[Distance] IN { "less than 2m" }
)
```

However, the filter doesn't seem to apply properly.

I want...

```
+------+--------------+--------------+--+
| Descr| less than 2m | more than 2m |  |
+------+--------------+--------------+--+
| Car  |            2 |            1 |  |
| Sign |            4 |            2 |  |
+------+--------------+--------------+--+
```

but I'm getting...

```
+------+--------------+--------------+--+
| Descr| less than 2m | more than 2m |  |
+------+--------------+--------------+--+
| Car  |            3 |            3 |  |
| Sign |            6 |            6 |  |
+------+--------------+--------------+--+
```

It's just giving me the total count by type which is correct but isn't applying the filter by distance so I can break it down.

I'm sure this is probably really simple but I'm pretty new with DAX and I can't figure this one out.

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted your relationship diagram and what `Subject[Distance]` looks like.

Comment: You would need filter propagation from 'subject' to 'main'. Take a look at `CROSSFILTER` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/crossfilter-function

Comment: Thanks, Kosuke!  The cross filter worked.  There was nothing wrong with the measure, it just couldn't filter across the two tables.

Answer (score 0):

I wish I could mark Kosuke's comment as an answer.  The issue was indeed with having to enable cross-filtering.  This can either be done clicking on the link on your model or using a function to temporarily enable the cross filter.